Android Studio Emulator Terminated with exit code -1073741515
I am trying to run the Pixel 7 API TiramisuPrivacySandbox and it keeps on terminate. I tried to search for errors in the log file and the error I can locate in the log file is:
SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null 
I tried to search for solutions over the internet and still cant solve the anomaly.
I tried updating, redownloading or other approaches like reconfiguring the settings or even checking whether somewhere is wrong, but I just don't understand what is "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()"
(I forget the solutions I tried but it includes wiping data, making new devices)
the "log snippet" are as following:
2024-10-07 20:36:56,452 [4719094] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.ChooseSystemImagePanel.isBaseExtensionLevelForDeviceType(ChooseSystemImagePanel.java:444)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.ChooseSystemImagePanel.getClassificationFromParts(ChooseSystemImagePanel.java:197)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.ChooseSystemImagePanel.getClassificationForDevice(ChooseSystemImagePanel.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.ChooseSystemImagePanel.getClassification(ChooseSystemImagePanel.java:166)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.ChooseSystemImagePanel$ClassificationRowFilter.include(ChooseSystemImagePanel.java:477)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.include(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.initializeFilteredMapping(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.allRowsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ui.table.TableView.tableChanged(TableView.java:74)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.ListTableModel.setItems(ListTableModel.java:87)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.SystemImageListModel.setItems(SystemImageListModel.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ui.SystemImageListModel.lambda$refreshImages$2(SystemImageListModel.java:147)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:887)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:469)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1763)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1712)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1726)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avd.AvdManagerImpl$createAvd$3.invokeSuspend(LocalEmulatorProvisionerFactory.kt:91)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:229)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2024-10-07 20:36:56,484 [4719126] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1  Build #AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432
2024-10-07 20:36:56,484 [4719126] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - JDK: 21.0.3; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-10-07 20:36:56,484 [4719126] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - OS: Windows 11
2024-10-07 20:36:56,528 [4719170]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb
2024-10-07 20:36:56,591 [4719233]   INFO - #com.android.adblib.impl.services.TrackDevicesService - "host:track-devices-proto-binary" - opening connection to ADB server, timeout: 4,997.0 msec remaining, 3.0 msec elapsed
2024-10-07 20:37:08,095 [4730737] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion.getExtensionLevel()" is null

